# How do I use listen for only 1 variable changing in React, while also using other variables?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to use functional React to build my (hobby) website. On there, I've run in to the following situation many times:

```js
const [randomData, setRandomData] = useState(true);
const [activePopup, setActivePopup] = useState(1);

useEffect(() => {
    ...
    console.log(randomData);
}, [activePopup])
```

(For clarity, this is a fictional example).

I'm trying to achieve that the code inside the `useEffect` block runs when `activePopup` changes, and only then, but I also need to access other properties and states. In VS Code, this results in a warning, mentioning that the hook has missing dependencies, and those should be added, or the dependency array should be removed.

In theory, I get why `useEffect` wants all variables in the dependency array: If `randomData` changes without `activePopup` changing, this `useEffect` call won't run. But what if it doesn't have to, and I only need to access it whenever I open a popup?

I get that a question like this usually means the structure of the code is bad, but for a situation like "I want to know / do something with the value of variable X only when I open a popup", I honestly can't think of a reason to included that variable X in the dependency array. Maybe `useEffect` isn't the proper way to handle this, and I guess some would recommend to handle using the variable in the same place where the popup is opened, but given the usage of a few contexts, simply listening for a change on the `activePopup` value is SO much simpler and easier to read.

Is it fine to just leave `randomData` out of the dependency array, and ignore the warning? Is there a different way to respond to the change of a variable? How do I handle this situation?

**Simplified**
If `activePopup` changes => Do something with `randomData`.
Do **NOT** run the same code when `randomData` changes.

Comment: Add it to the dependency array and use `if (activePopup)` in the callback

Comment: Leaving out one dependency in your effect means when your effect is executed randomData might be stale. You might misunderstand dependencies. If ONE of them changes, your effect is executed. There is not need for both to change. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect for reference.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Doesn't that only check if `activePopup` is truthy? In my case, `activePopup` will always be set to a number, so it's always truthy. If there's a way to check which variable change caused the call, I'd love to know about that.

Comment: @nil No, I understand dependencies, that's exactly why I **don't** want `randomData` in the dependency array. `randomData` can change as much as it wants to, but I **don't** want `useEffect` to be called when `randomData` changes, it **only** needs to be called when `activePopup` changes. I don't understand how `randomData` could be stale: as far as I've seen, when I use the above example, `randomData` is available inside `useEffect` as what it was when `activePopup` changed, which is what I need. If I understand correctly, it would only become stale if `useEffect` takes a long time to run.

Comment: Why is `activePopup` a number? Are you keeping track of multiple popups? Would it fit your case to change activePopup to a boolean and then make a condition inside the `useEffect` where you check if `activePopup === true`. Can you provide more info on the desired functionality?

Comment: @VilfredDreijer Thing is: that doesn't have anything to do with my question. I know how to check if the popup opened or closed. What I want to know is if I absolutely must add `randomData` to the dependency array, or if it's OK to leave it out. What I want to do is extremely simple: `activePopup changes => use randomData for something`. I do NOT want to run that code when `randomData` changes.

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a way to implement your wish without the dependencies. But to answer your question, you can choose to only give it `activePopup` and it will compile and work. you can also include `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` one line above the dependency array to ignore the warning. Just understand the consequences. But yes, it's doable

Comment: @Timmiej93 I would say it is still recommended to adhere to that rule. Does randomData need to be part of the state? If not, just use a ref. If it needs to, you can use a ref to point to current state value and use that ref in your effect. See here an example for often changing deps: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often

Answer (score 2):

Without more detail it's kind of difficult to give an answer that applies to all possible cases of this scenario, but the gist is no, violating the exhaustive-deps rule is never necessary to solve any specific problem.

One of the simplest tricks is to apply [`useRef()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) in order to that ensure `randomData` isn't accessed from a stale closure:

```
const [randomData, setRandomData] = useState(true);
const [activePopup, setActivePopup] = useState(1);

const randomDataRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  randomDataRef.current = randomData;
}, [randomData]);

useEffect(() => {
    // log randomData only when activePopup changes
    console.log(randomDataRef.current);
}, [activePopup]);
```

This works because the return value of a call to `useRef()` is exempt from the exhaustive-deps rule. Regardless of whether it's in the array or not, the behavior doesn't change, and its reference can never be stale by design. This is exactly equivalent to the above due to `randomDataRef` being memoized by React:

```
const [randomData, setRandomData] = useState(true);
const [activePopup, setActivePopup] = useState(1);

const randomDataRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  randomDataRef.current = randomData;
}, [randomData, randomDataRef]);
//              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

useEffect(() => {
    // log randomData only when activePopup changes
    console.log(randomDataRef.current);
}, [activePopup, randomDataRef]);
//               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

For the record, the same reasoning applies as to why the setters returned by `useState()` and the dispatch function from `useReducer()` are also exempt from the exhaustive-deps rule; they're all memoized by React so including them in or omitting them from the dependency array makes no difference to the behavior of `useEffect()`.

Comment: Could you include an example of a stale closure in your answer (that actually results in stale data)? I have been trying, but I simply cannot get stale data. The `useRef` trick is pretty nice, I'll have to remember that, thanks.

Comment: @Timmiej93 In your original example, if the `console.log()` is within an asynchronous callback, it's very easy for `randomData` to come from a stale closure. The thing to be careful with `useRef()` is that the point you access `ref.current` should align with when you use it, e.g. don't store `const randomDataValue = randomDataRef.current;` synchronously in the `useEffect()` and then `console.log(randomDataValue);` in an asynchronous callback, because that defeats the purpose of `useRef()` keeping a live reference to the updated `randomData` via the `current` property.